# Как отсортировать два разных массива в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, сортировка, recyclerview, firebase

У меня есть 5 элементов в RecyclerView (элементы, взяты из базы данных) с датами и текстами. Два разных списка. Для дат и для строк. Один фрагмент содержит 1 дату и 1 строку текста. Итак, мне нужно отсортировать элементы по дате, вот так

**Результат который мне нужен**

```
text1 10.09.2021
text2 13.09.2021
text3 30.09.2021
text4 1.12.2021
```

**Нынешний результат**

```
text3 30.09.2021
text4 1.12.2021
text1 10.09.2021
text2 13.09.2021
```

Тексты и даты это два разных ArrayList'a

Суть вопроса в том, что как я могу отсортировав даты к примеру и отсортировать текст по таким же позициям как и даты? Либо это можно сделать как то одновременно?

Получаю данные с Firebase и отправляю в адаптер

```java
        List<String> reminder = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> date = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar test = Calendar.getInstance();
        long pars = test.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println(pars);


        dbf.child("Reminders").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                reminder.clear();
                date.clear();


                for(DataSnapshot child2 : snapshot.getChildren()) { // getting a data from DB to ArrayList for dropping into Adapter

                    for(DataSnapshot tChild : child2.getChildren()) {
                        if (tChild.getKey().equals("text")) {
                            reminder.add(tChild.getValue().toString());
                            rem = reminder.toArray(new String[reminder.size()]);

                        }
                        if (tChild.getKey().equals("date")) {
                            date.add(tChild.getValue().toString());
                            dat = date.toArray(new String[date.size()]);


                        }

                    }



                    mainRowAdapter rAdapter = new mainRowAdapter(MainActivity.this, rem,dat);
                    rv.setAdapter(rAdapter);
                    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

выставление текста в адаптере

```java
        holder.reminder.setText(reminder[position]);
        holder.date.setText(date[position]);
```

Как я пробовал сортировать даты - сортировка правильная, остается только понять как к этому добавить нужный текст

```java
                            Collections.sort(date, new Comparator<String>() {
                                DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy");
                                @Override
                                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                                    try {
                                        return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));

                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Я пробовал сортировать даты перед отправкой в адаптер и сверять с бд на наличие текста сортированной даты, но ничего толкового не вышло

UPDATED:

в комментариях порекомендовали получать объект и сортировать его по полю date. я попробовал получать список в List, но как его отсортировать так и не понимаю. Вот что из этого вышло

```
[text3 30.09.2021, text4 1.12.2021, text1 10.09.2021, text2 13.09.2021]
```

Comment: Это возможно только при сортировке собственным кодом. Проще объединить оба списка в один, а после сортировать. Ещё лучше сразу из базы получать пару в виде объекта, соответственно запрос выдаёт список объектов, дальше сортируем его по полю `date` и всё.

Comment: с объединением списков вряд ли получится, они же объединяются в одну строку, а с объектами попробую

Comment: не получилось отсортировать @woesss

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    private static final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("text3", "text1", "text2"));
    private static final List<Date> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Date(1000000000), new Date(1), new Date(100000)));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListSorter listSorter = new ListSorter();
        listSorter.sort(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(listSorter.getList1());
        System.out.println(listSorter.getList2());
    }

    static class ListSorter {

        private static class Entry {

            private final String s;
            private final Date d;

            public Entry(String s, Date d) {
                if (s == null || d == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("null field in entry");
                }
                this.s = s;
                this.d = d;
            }

        }
        private final List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        private final Comparator<Entry> comparator = (e1, e2) -> {
            if (e1 == null && e2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (e1 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (e2 == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return e1.d.compareTo(e2.d);
        };

        public void sort(List<String> list1,
                         List<Date> list2) {
            if (list1 == null || list2 == null || list1.size() != list2.size()) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("list is null or sizes not identical");
            }
            entries.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                entries.add(new Entry(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
            }
            entries.sort(comparator);
        }

        public List<String> getList1() {
            return entries.stream()
                    .map(e -> e.s)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public List<Date> getList2() {
            return entries.stream()
                    .map(e -> e.d)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    }

}
```